# Need help sql "LIKE" operator

Tags: php, mysql

Users on my site get to add their friends. The way i am trying to do it is when they add a new friend It updates the "friends" column so.. if the user "bobby" had friends named tom and Joe already and they want to add another friend "bob" it will update the column so it would now look like " tom, joe, bob, ect.." so.. my issue is each one of these friends has data in a table called `items` with their information age, city etc.. when bobby hits the button "show()" I need it to retrieve each friend that is in "bobby's" friend column with their info. So this is where I am at.

```
$show = mysql_query("SELECT `friends` FROM `Friends` WHERE`Username`='".$_SESSION['Username']."' ") or die(mysql_error());
$showw = mysql_fetch_object($show) or die(mysql_error());
$yup = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `items` WHERE Username LIKE '%".($showw->friends)."%' ") or die(mysql_error());
```

It won't return any data because i can't figure out a way for it to sort through then names. Can I tell it to get each name after each comma?

Comment: Your should probably have a separate table for user-friend relationships.

Comment: Normalise your database so that there is a new table for relationships. This should be covered fairly early on in your databases textbook.

Comment: Sorry,  for the confusion. I do have 2 seperate tables for the users. I have a table called members which stores all info once regisrered and then i created the table friends which has the rows username and friends. I am kinda new to php and sql sorry. I try to do as much research as possible when i get stumped like this..

Answer (score 1):

First off, you **should** have a separate table to map the friends to a particular user. You will face a lot of complications if you continue it the way you have now.

Anyway, even though this is not recommended, in your case,

```
$show = mysql_query("SELECT `friends` FROM `Friends` WHERE`Username`='".$_SESSION['Username']."' ") or die(mysql_error());
$showw = mysql_fetch_object($show) or die(mysql_error());

$friends = "'" . str_replace(", ", "', '", $showw->friends) . "'";
$yup = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `items` WHERE Username IN (". $friends .") ") or die(mysql_error());
```

`IN` will filter match all the comma separated values.

PS: Please consider using PDO or any other database library as `mysql_*` functions are getting deprecated over the next release :)

Comment: This just makes it worse! Now your string-contained data is injected outside of a string context, which is more than a little dangerous. And you probably need to inject new quotation marks to make it work anyway..

Comment: So is thier a different  way i should be inserting the names into the friends column. To make make it more safe/ logical?